# Из какой переменной окружения cgi приложение берет путь к файлу, который нужно исполнить?

Tags: http, cgi, http-server

Из какой переменной окружения cgi приложение берет путь к файлу, который нужно исполнить? И должен ли в этой переменной лежать только путь, или путь с файлом.

Comment: cgi-приложению нет никакого смысла искать путь к самому себе, потому что оно и так уже запущено, так что ни из какой

Comment: @andreymal, но оно же исполняет определенный сценарий, к нему должен быть указан путь

Comment: Кажется, вы путаете cgi приложение с сервером, которое запускает это самое cgi-приложение. Сценарий это и есть cgi-приложение, а сервер и без всяких переменных знает из адресной строки, какой файл ему запускать

Comment: @andreymal, в моем понимании, cgi сервер является тем же сценарием, который заполняет необходимые данные(как $_GET, $_POST...), и запускает(вставляет) необходимый скрипт, который выполняет свою работу на основе этих данных, или я ошибаюсь? cgi сервер все равно должен знать, в какой директории лежимт необходимый скрипт, или на этот счет нет строгих правил ?

Comment: В cgi не существует никаких $_GET и $_POST.

Comment: Кажется, теперь вы уже путаете cgi и php.

Comment: @andreymal, я спрашиваю напримере php cgi

Comment: В таком случае сервер передаёт путь к нужному php-скрипту программе php-cgi через первый аргумент командной строки

Comment: Впрочем, гугл сообщает, что php-cgi также может принимать переменную окружения SCRIPT_FILENAME, видимо это то что вы хотели

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо, я пытаюсь разобраться в этой теме, по этому много путаюсь. Через php-cgi можно запустить любой скрипт с расширением php?

Comment: Ну по крайней мере я не знаю причин, которые мешали бы запускать «любой» php-скрипт, настройки безопасности разве что

Comment: @andreymal, если можно, еще вопрос. на примере php. Cgi сценарии - это обычные скрипты, которые просто вставляются в cgi сервер, который заполняет все необходимые данные, или cgi-скрипты должны быть написаны так, чтоб самостоятельно заполнять данные из потока ввода и переменных окружения?

Comment: Нету никаких cgi сценариев и скриптов, это обычные программы, которые запускаются как любые другие программы и которым сервер передаёт информацию самыми обычными путями - стандартный ввод и переменные окружения, как и в любой другой программе. Точный формат данных, которые может передать тот кто запускает cgi-программу, описан в RFC 3875

Comment: Точнее, с «нету никаких» слегка перебор - скрипт/сценарий может запускаться и работать как обычная программа, если это поддерживается операционной системой

Comment: @andreymal, я просто не могу понять, при запуске скрипта http-сервером в режиме cgi, нужен ли серверу "посредник"? Т.е программа, например php скрипт, которая будет заполнять все необходимые данные(суперглобальные массивы и тд), или этот интерфейс подразумивает запуск необходимого скрипта напрямую(просто с необходимыме параметрами окружения), но в таком случае, сам скрипт должен заботиться о заполнении необходимых данных.

Comment: Всему, что не является машинным кодом подходящим для текущего процессора, необходимо что-то, что будет его интерпретировать, и в случае с php этим «что-то» оказывается программа php-cgi (которая уже на машинном коде и которую запускать можно без проблем). Что интерфейс подразумевает и что передаёт, описано в RFC 3875, и всякие $_GET и $_POST не имеют никакого отношения к cgi и в данном случае являются особенностью работы конкретно php

Comment: А в 2020 году точно надо обсуждать cgi? Может всё-таки fastcgi (fcgi)?